# <merge> in Fragment

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have a fragment `VideoListPagerFragment`. It was VideoListDemoActivity from YoutubePlayer API Android sample. I made fragment from that sample activity, but i need to fix one error.
I init my Fragment like:

Code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.videos_fragmentpage,container,true);
someAnotherMethods();
returt view;
}
```

FRAGMENT XML(R.layout.videos_fragmentpage):

```
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    >
    <fragment
        class="com.alexpoltavets.fifacommunity.videos.VideoListPagerFragment$VideoListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/video_box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/close_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"
            android:onClick="onClickClose"/>

        <fragment
            class="com.alexpoltavets.fifacommunity.videos.VideoListPagerFragment$VideoFragment"
            android:id="@+id/video_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

But, when i start my Activity:
  Code of adding fragment:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.videos_container,VideoListPagerFragment.newInstance(),"test")
            .commit();
```

Activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/videos_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

I have an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alexpoltavets.fifacommunity/com.alexpoltavets.fifacommunity.videos.VideosActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

If i change:

```
  View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.videos_fragmentpage,container,true);
```

to:

```
  View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.videos_fragmentpage,container,false);
```

i will have:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alexpoltavets.fifacommunity/com.alexpoltavets.fifacommunity.videos.VideosActivity}: android.view.InflateException: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true
```

If i change `<marge>` to another container like `<FrameLayout>` it fix this error, but when screen rotate to landscape, i have another bug with 2 similar fragment on one screen.

How i can fix it?

Comment: You forgot to add the `<include />` tag. https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: Where? How? Example please...

Comment: Click on the link in my prior comment. You should ALWAYS read the official docs.

Comment: I read this link yeasterday. But i still don't understand. I use Fragment dynamically, where i must use <include/>?

Comment: Obviously enough, in the layout which will include the merged one.

Comment: I want to use ViewPager with few Fragments like this. It just Example. If i will use <include> it will destroy dynamically adding, isnt it?

Comment: No, wait... You can simply **replace** the Fragments dynamically. You don't need to **include** any Fragment at all. Just have an empty placeholder in your Activity. Then replace its content by simply replacing the placeholder with a Fragment. You actually miss the fundamentals. Again, please **refer to the official docs**.

Comment: And also mind the typo, here: `returt view;`

Comment: @Rotwang i will try. Thanks.